# StackOverFlowError while doing a One-To-One relationship in GAE Datastore using JPA 2.0

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I have two tables `Folder` & `VirtualSystemEntry` I tried to follow this [Dataneclous Turorial](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jpa/orm/one_to_one.html) but it always results with `StackOverFlowException` here what I tried so far

Folder.java

```
@Entity
public class Folder implements IsSerializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fvseID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String fvseID;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vseID")
    private VirtualSystemEntry vse=new VirtualSystemEntry();
}
```

VirtualSystemEntry.java

```
@Entity
public class VirtualSystemEntry implements IsSerializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "vseID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String id;
    String label, image, tooltip;


    private int x, y, tray;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="vse")
    Folder parent = new Folder();
    }
```

Piece of the Exception Trace

```
INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:334)
    at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:932)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:653)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:63)
    at com.cbd.shared.entities.VirtualSystemEntry.&lt;init&gt;(VirtualSystemEntry.java:28)
    at com.cbd.shared.entities.Folder.&lt;init&gt;(Folder.java:27)
    at com.cbd.shared.entities.VirtualSystemEntry.&lt;init&gt;(VirtualSystemEntry.java:28)
    at com.cbd.shared.entities.Folder.&lt;init&gt;(Folder.java:27)
    at com.cbd.shared.entities.VirtualSystemEntry.&lt;init&gt;(VirtualSystemEntry.java:28)
    at com.cbd.shared.entities.Folder.&lt;init&gt;(Folder.java:27)
    at com.cbd.shared.entities.VirtualSystemEntry.&lt;init&gt;(VirtualSystemEntry.java:28)
    at com.cbd.shared.entities.Folder..... and so on
```

So What am I doing wrong right here ?? by the way I'm Using `GWT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code `VirtualSystemEntry(constructor)` is calling your code `Folder(constructor)`, which recurses (and you don't provide the code of those methods), likely the initialisation of those class variables "parent" and "vse" ... fix the initialisation ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for reply I was sure that you will answer this question first :).
So, I think you mean by that is to remove the assigned Objects from each reference on both : eg:`Folder parent;`
right? Because I actually depend on default constructor on both due to `JPA` issues with constructors with arguments