# encounter java.lang.StackOverflowError when used @OneToOne for select in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

when I test some things about mapping relationship of @OneToOne in Hibernate, and I use spring-data-jpa to query. For the bidirectional relationship of the @OneToOne, when I query an entity, it will occurred two conditions:

- when no data in two tables, no errors;
- when data is stored in two tables, just StackOverflowError;

the related code in the next:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer personId;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private IdCard idCard;
    // setter&getter
}

@Entity
public class IdCard {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer number;
    private String area;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="idCard")
    private Person person;
}
```

PersonDao:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface PersonDao extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {
    public Person findByPersonId(Integer personId);
}
```

IdCardDao:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface IdCardDao extends CrudRepository<IdCard, Integer> {
    public IdCard findByNumber (Integer number);
}
```

test code:

```
Person person = personDao.findByPersonId(1);
System.out.println(person);
IdCard idCard = idCardDao.findByNumber(123);
System.out.println(idCard);
```

I search some answers in the website, find a related question, [StackOverFlowError while doing a One-To-One relationship in GAE Datastore using JPA 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855390/stackoverflowerror-while-doing-a-one-to-one-relationship-in-gae-datastore-using)

but I did not instantiate the entity explicitly, so no recurses. use jpa 2.1
Any solutions?

Comment: Well you obviously have something in your code causing this however your failure to post the exception  message and the associated code means no one can help you!

Comment: You do System.out.println(person); So have you overriden toString() in these classes? You may have recursive call here.

Comment: @Alan Hay yes, I override ToString(), as you see:`@Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Person [personId=" + personId + ", name=" + name +      ", idCard=" + idCard + "]";
 }`

Comment: Post the code then.

Comment: Yes, `idCard=" + idCard`  makes an implicit call to `idCard.toString()` and I'm guessing toString in IdCard calls `person=" + person` and there's your infinite  loop.

Comment: yes, I have got it, the `toString()` results in the infinite loop, without it, the test works. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in `@OneToOne` relationship, and the solution for the `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null` is **to use fetch LAZY in the owing side** of the relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer personId;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private IdCard idCard;
    // setter&getter
}

@Entity
public class IdCard {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer number;
    private String area;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="idCard")
    private Person person;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, you can map with one end., for OneToOne and ManyToOne at the receiving end you don't need to mention,

```
@Entity
public class Person {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer personId;
private String name;
@OneToOne
private IdCard idCard;
// setter&getter
}

@Entity
public class IdCard {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer number;
private String area;

private Person person;
}
```

Comment: I use the `@OneToOne` to establish a undirectional relationship before, it works well as you mentioned above, but when establish a bidirectional relationship will result in the problem.

Comment: If I'm right, circular reference is the problem. Can you run that url with rest client? so that we can know the response and problem.